# Universal Maps and Adjunctions

Tags: category-theory

A Universal morphism from X to a functor F is a pair $(A, u : X → F A)$ such that there exists a unique map $A → A'$ such that the following diagram commutes

[image: Unique Mapping Property for u]

In other words, $(A, u)$ it is the initial object in the slice category $\mathcal{C}/F$.

Is the UMP for $u$ always arising from an adjunction?
In particular, is it true that I can always define a $G$ to be the left adjoint of $F$ such that $GX = A$?

If not, is there a UMP for a particular $u$ that does not arise from an adjunction?

Comment: i do not see how for example UMP of categorical product comes from an adjunction

Comment: @AlekseiKubanov it does though. I believe it is one of the adjoints of the diagonal functor, the other one being coproducts.

Comment: I reformulated the question. @AlekseiKubanov, the product is the right adjoint to the diagonal functor and the coproduction is the left adjoint to the diagonal functor.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the $G$ you define is a left adjoint iff there is a universal morphism from $X$ to $F$ for *every* $X$. I'm also pretty sure there are cases where some objects have a universal morphism to $F$ but other objects don't, and in that case $F$ won't have a left adjoint. I don't have a specific example in mind right now though.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_property#Relation_to_adjoint_functors) is what you are looking for?

Comment: @Markix I see now. But then every limit comes from an adjunction: If $I$ is an indexing category, $C$ has all limits of form $I$, then $\lim : [I, C] \to C$ is right adjoint to $\Delta : C \to [I, C]$, which maps $c \in C$ to the constant functor taking each $i \in I$ to $c$ and each map in $I$ to $\mathrm{id}_c$. And $\mathrm{colim}$ is left adjoint. Now, in particular, you are interested in an initial object in slice category $C/F$ -- that is, in the colimit of empty diagram -- and the corresponding functor $1 = [\varnothing, C/F] \to C/F$ is left adjoint to the trivial functor $C/F \to 1$

Comment: @azif00 that is exactly where my diagram is from. The problem is that in the wikipedia page it says smth like "If for every $X$ you can construct an $A$  with a universal map $u : X → FA$  then the assignment $X \mapsto A$ forms a functor $G$ which is right adjoint". But this is a big "if", no? I was wondering if there is a counterexample.